# mixpanel.track() returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, mixpanel

I'm trying to implement mixpanel script into my react app.. as per the docs I've pasted the mixpanel snippet inside index.html inside the head tag & the token key is also set.

But i still get this msg shown below inside my mixpanel dashboard.
[image]

In this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/odIX1oJlsjo?list=PLMiVDxjrWjsZbuRmP-STJrCllSjEJid_A&t=234) we can trigger an event from console.log and can see the event in mixpanel dashboard but when i try to do the same mixpanel.track returns undefined.. instead it should have returned an object as shown in the video.

[image]

I then tried to follow this article from medium.. https://medium.com/@andrewoons/setting-up-mixpanel-in-react-3e4c5b8c2a36. but still no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main culprit is the browser settings..

Go to browser settings > Privacy and security > Cookies and other site data

Turn Off Send

```
‘Do Not Track’ request with your browsing traffic
```

Enable

```
Allow all cookies
```

[image]

This should fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

set:

```
const trackAutomaticEvents = true;
const mixpanel = new Mixpanel("Your Project Token", trackAutomaticEvents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Mohammed's suggestion works. Rather than fight Chrome's permission UI, I tested console in Safari and then I saw my test event "Jono Force" in the Live Event view.

[image]